# Using node.js with a titanium or alloy project

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy

I want to use the following library with my Titanium/ Alloy project:

https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string

It can be installed using nodeJS.

However, Alloy typically only allows files coming from the lib folder.

According to: https://archive.appcelerator.com/question/154529/how-to-use-nodejs-modules-with-titanium#answer-285207

they used a copy and paste method, but this won't be suitable as this specific has dependencies.

How can I do this?

Comment: If the dependencies are core modules you cannot, if dependencies are standalone libs just put them in the nodemodules dir too

Comment: as long as the dependencies aren't requiring core modules themselves

Comment: So where do I put the `node_modules` directory? In the `lib` directory?

Answer (score 0):

Prior to Titanium SDK 6.0.0 the copy/paste method was the only way to use node modules.

With the Titanium SDK 6.0.0 and going forward there is official support to use npm packages. The release notes are [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_SDK_6.0.0.GA_Release_Note) and the Jira ticket [TIMOB-16078](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-16078) that tracked this feature request.

Comment: So how exactly do we use it. For example where do we place the `node_modules` folder?